# I have a paragraph and I want to find out correlation of every word with every other word. How can I do that using Python

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I want to find out the correlation on the basis of their usage and not the similarity between two words with their association strength. How can I do that?
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214301/finding-word-association-strengths-from-an-input-text Is this the correct way to achieve the desired output or is there any other better way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at linguistics literature? Under _collocation_ you might find something that answers your question.

Comment: @OliverMason https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214301/finding-word-association-strengths-from-an-input-text Is this the correct way to achieve the desired output or is there any other better way?